# Object-Oriented JavaScript tools

Tags: javascript, jquery, architecture, mootools, prototypejs

I have been working on the user interface of my website ([www.swalif.com](http://swalif.com): do use chrome to translate if you like to). Not being familiar with jQuery I started off with JavaScript and now the file is huge: about 1000 lines of code. Furthermore the code is getting complex to handle and change.

Therefore I was looking for a way I could approach this problem in an object oriented manner that would result in a clean, re-usable system with a good architecture. **Also would be nice to use features as provided by JQuery to keep the code small**.

The problem is that there are a lot of tools out there and I cannot decide which one to invest time into to accomplish this task. e.g. mootools, prototype, jQuery, etc. So I need someone to lead me in the right direction.

This is our website [www.swalif.com](http://swalif.com). Any other suggestion are also welcome.

Comment: I suggest you start by reading [*Working with objects*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

Comment: Do you want to rewrite all the javascript using a framework, or just refactor the code?

Comment: @Jon Abaca :  don't mind rewriting the code

Comment: I'd suggest you to use JQuery in the list of tools you mentionned: It's very well documented, supported, lots of plugins and it won't conflict like prototype or mootools which alter/poison the global space and host objects methods. for object inheritence, you just can pick any 'extend' implementation out there

Answer (score 3):

For object-oriented javascript development I would recommend John Resig's [Simple javascript Inheritance](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/). It is a tiny bit of javascript that allows you to define classes, derive from base classes and override methods.

```
var Person = Class.extend({
  init: function(isDancing){
    this.dancing = isDancing;
  },
  dance: function(){
    return this.dancing;
  }
});
var Ninja = Person.extend({
  init: function(){
    this._super( false );
  },
  dance: function(){
    // Call the inherited version of dance()
    return this._super();
  },
  swingSword: function(){
    return true;
  }
});

var p = new Person(true);
p.dance(); // => true

var n = new Ninja();
n.dance(); // => false
n.swingSword(); // => true

// Should all be true
p instanceof Person && p instanceof Class &&
n instanceof Ninja && n instanceof Person && n instanceof Class
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you'd be better off with a framework that actively developed and is build with OOP with extendability, reusability, mixings, mutators in mind.

This is exactly why **MooTools** was created.

That said, if you're not familiar with JS, it would be pretty difficult to grasp MooTools, since it's not a framework for beginners. Then again, if you grasp the notion of OOP, you should be ok.

Answer (score 3):

Don't actually use a framework to implement your OOP. You get a much richer understanding of Javascript as a language when you deal with the nitty gritty of using Javascript's *very* flexible function prototype system to implement OOP-like operations.

Read about it here: http://phrogz.net/JS/Classes/OOPinJS.html.

Comment: I second that, it's really helpful to try manual class definition and inheritance in JS and understand how it works.

Comment: why reinvent the wheel? while it is nice to know how it works, getting a full oop implementation right isn't that easy

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to organize your code and don't need libraries you may use http://code.google.com/p/joose-js/. Otherwise use the oop model of the library you are using.

Simple example

```
Module("Test", function (m) {
    Class("Point", {
        has: {
            x: {
                is:   "rw",
                init: 0
            },
            y: {
                is:   "rw",
                init: 0
            }
        },
        methods: {
            clear: function () {
                this.setX(0);
                this.setY(0);
            }
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: ok another addition to the list: mootools, prototype, Jquery, Juice

Comment: well javascript is very flexible. it gives you the power to choose. Juice is one option that will give you very powerful and easy to write oop.